# Fix error: Unable to resolve dependency 'System.Composition.Runtime'. Source(s) used: 'DemoPakage', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages'

Tags: c#

Can you help me fix error: Fix error: Unable to resolve dependency 'System.Composition.Runtime'. Source(s) used: 'DemoPakage', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages'.

I am using C# VS-2017/

Fix error: Unable to resolve dependency 'System.Composition.Runtime'. Source(s) used: 'DemoPakage', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages'.             *your text*

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre].

Comment: Did check if nuget org is configured as source for the packages?

Comment: i'm a new user. i don't know how to upload my project here/ Please give me your email. i will send you my project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.